# JMX + Supporting Web GUI

Tags: java, jmx

There is web application running on WebLogic. I have enabled the JMX monitoring on it by adding below system properties:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

From my local command prompt, I am able to connect this using `<server_name>:<port>`

My question is, are there any open-source tools which provides out-of-the-box GUI (web-pages) through which I can monitor? I would like to embed functionality in my existing web-app and hence looking forward for any out-of-the-box tools.

Comment: You could always use Jconsole or visualVM. Do you specifically want web pages alone ?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/jminix/

Comment: JConsole is working fine, I am looking for webpages so that it can be monitored by the admin users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [JMiniX](https://code.google.com/p/jminix/). JMiniX can be used through a servlet or as an embedded web-server in stand-alone applications.

Comment: Thanks, I will explore JMiniX, are there any other tools?